# Spark Parallelized Collectios

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I am very new to Spark, I can't run a parallelize collection, this is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc

words = [
    'Apache', 'Spark', 'is', 'an', 'open-source', 'cluster-computing',
    'framework', 'Apache', 'Spark', 'open-source', 'Spark'
]

# Creates a RDD from a list of words

distributed_words = sc.parallelize(words)
distributed_words.count()
```

**And I get:**

```
TypeError: parallelize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
why?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `spark Context` we can get that from `Spark Session` starting from `Spark-2` then `parallelize` the words collection.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext
words = [
    'Apache', 'Spark', 'is', 'an', 'open-source', 'cluster-computing',
    'framework', 'Apache', 'Spark', 'open-source', 'Spark'
]
distributed_words = sc.parallelize(words)
distributed_words.count()
#11
```